# SQL 2014 CAL License Verification

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a client who recently purchased SQL 2014 Enterprise Edition with 5 CAL licenses. The installation was done remotely. 
Question is how does one go about verifying that there are indeed 5 CAL licenses that are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't verify this. There is no method.
The licensing deal is between the client and Microsoft.

There are indirect methods, say if they have a public web site then CALs are useless and they should have core licences.
How to to plan to enforce such a thing on behalf of Microsoft anyway?